# Send JSON response from Sqlite queries in Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a Python http server which listens to JSON based requests. After receiving the request, it parses the key from the JSON input, and queries Sqlite database which has such a key. Now I want to respond the request with a result JSON message. I am new to Python, and I don't know how.

My code structure is like below:

```
 import ...

 key=...;//get key from request
 con = lite.connect('test.db')
 with con:
    con.row_factory = lite.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable ");
    while True:

        row = cur.fetchone()

        if row == None:
            break
        if key==row['key']:
            # How can I add the record to the response?
```

And the handler will write the response like this (in a class inherit BaseHTTPRequestHandler and started by a thread)

```
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(??????) # What do I need to write here?
```

Comment: import json;
self.wfile.write(json.dumps(yourdict))

Comment: @gosom How can I organize such a dict from the sqlite result/rows? I use LocalData.records[row[0]]=row to store each matching row, and self.wfile.write(json.dumps(LocalData.records)) to write to the output. It says "... is not JSON serializable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning JSON response is as easy as that:

```
import json
import sqlite3

def get_my_jsonified_data(key):
    with sqlite3.connect('test.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column=?;", [key])
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return json.dumps(data)
```

(assuming that `lite` is an alias for `sqlite3`)

Note few other things:

1. I've removed `while True:` loop. It's horribly inefficient, insecure and harder to read;
2. I've added check for `key` inside the SQL query (why would you want to load the unnecessary data from DB anyway?)

Comment: Thanks. For the checking for key, it is my fault as I am adding the codes piece by piece so that's not necessary obviously (just use sql). Another question is that fetchall() could have problems (memory, response size, etc.) if the result is big?

Comment: @mrmoment Unless you are doing a streaming (which doesn't look like that) then you have to load all the data into memory anyway.   And if you are doing a streaming then use `cursor.fetchamany(10000)` for example. Fetching item by item is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Got it. I think I can use "limit" clause to reduce the results for fetchall(). Thanks again.

Comment: When I try this in Python3, I get `TypeError: Object of type 'Row' is not JSON serializable` on json.dumps(data). Do you need to configure anything else?

Comment: @PrahladYeri It seems that you are using `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` somewhere. In that situation you can try `json.dumps([tuple(row) for row in data])`.

Comment: @freakish that `json.dumps([tuple(row) for row in data])` solution from your comment works like a charm.

Comment: @freakish you solution 'json.dumps([tuple(row) for row in data])' in the comment work for me! Saved my day!

Comment: @freakish tried what you said and get Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: @Scott I don't know your specific case, however if you keep binary column in your database then JSON serialization won't work, because JSON does not support this kind of data type. You may want to convert such column to base64 or hex string. If you don't know how to do that, or are confused, or the problem is elsewhere then feel free to ask a proper question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @freakish I tracked it down to another issue. Part of the reason i was trying to get the data out of python was that one of the columns was a pickled tuple. I forgot and turned off the unpickling when I was getting that error.

Answer (score 6):

you can try this

```py
import sqlite3


def row_to_dict(cursor: sqlite3.Cursor, row: sqlite3.Row) -> dict:
    data = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        data[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return data

with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as con:
    con.row_factory = row_to_dict
    result = con.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')
    print(result.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1):

Still don't have enough points to comment apparently.
@freakish - yes I'm using `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` to get the results as python dictionary and yes your solution does work, but it doesn't encode the result as a list of dictionaries using the column names as I need.

The problem, in essense, is that sqlite returns sqlite objects that json.dumps can't deal with. I need a way to create an output like this for 3 rows:

```
{
'json': [
         {'column1': value, 'column2': value, 'column3': value},
         {'column1': value, 'column2': value, 'column3': value},
         {'column1': value, 'column2': value, 'column3': value}
        ]
}
```

I believe this will do it, but not as cleanly as your 1 liner :)

```
rows = []
for row in data:
    cols = {}
    for col in row.keys():
        cols[col] = row[col]
    rows.append(cols)
jsn = json.dumps(rows)
```